# Assigning onclick via jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to assign an anchor's onclick via javascript - see jsfiddle below:

```
  <a id="link_a" class="linka" href="http://www.google.com">link 1</a>

   var lnkA=$('.linka'); 
   lnkA.onclick=function(){alert(this.innerHTML);};
```

fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/andrewtr/tkfvyr7o/ Code:

However, it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for jQuery https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lnkA` is a jQuery object which have a method called [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to register click handlers

```js
var lnkA = $('.linka');

lnkA.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();//to prevent redirection
  alert(this.innerHTML)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link_a" class="linka" href="http://www.google.com">link 1</a>
<a id="link_b" href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">link 2</a>
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/
- http://api.jquery.com/